# What does "=>" mean in Rust?

Tags: rust, syntax

I am trying to modify the VGA buffer's character. I don't understand the meaning of `=>`:

```
b'\n' => self.new_line()
```

Comment: In a `match`? What is the context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The context matters. I imagine this is probably from the middle of a match statement like this:

```rust
match foo {
    b'\n' => self.new_line(),
    // If foo is any other byte, do nothing (empty code block).
    _ => {}
}
```

In this case, `b'\n' => self.new_line()` roughly means "If the thing I am trying to match is the byte for a new line, call `self.new_line()`".

```rust
match a {
    // If a matches b do c, otherwise try next case
    b => c,
    // etc.
}
```

In C this would probably look a bit more like this:

```c
switch (foo) {
    case '\n':
        new_line(self);
        break;
    // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`=>` is used in `match` to denote the separation between the pattern and the arm expression or block.

From [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-02-match.html):

> ```rust
> enum Coin {
>     Penny,
>     Nickel,
>     Dime,
>     Quarter,
> }
>
> fn value_in_cents(coin: Coin) -> u8 {
>     match coin {
>         Coin::Penny => 1,
>         Coin::Nickel => 5,
>         Coin::Dime => 10,
>         Coin::Quarter => 25,
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Next are the match arms. An arm has two parts: a pattern and some code. The first arm here has a pattern that is the value `Coin::Penny` and then the `=>` operator that separates the pattern and the code to run. The code in this case is just the value `1`. Each arm is separated from the next with a comma.

In your case, the pattern is the `\n` byte, and the arm code is `self.new_line()`. This essentially says "when the input is the newline character, handle that with `self.new_line()`".